# Button 3 circle button that can rotate

Tags: android, button, shapes

I've been looking into an Android problem for some time. I have not found anything on the internet to advance this probelm...

I'm looking to make 3 buttons in a circle that would be one inside the other (See image)

The final objective is that I can insert an image in each of the buttons and that when I click on one, the latter rotates around the central point.

But for the moment I am already blocking the creation of the 3 buttons.
I tested this :

```
<shape
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:innerRadiusRatio="20"
 android:shape="ring"
 android:thicknessRatio="0"
 android:useLevel="false">
 <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
</shape>
```

But :
 1. The click is always on the last button which make sence...
 2. I don't know how i can add a image here

I have also try to draw the 3 circles in Paint and then use them as background Button with different height.
It works, but the shape of the button is still a rectangle. So it is not optimized.

Does anyone have a solution?
I know it is possible because i've seen that in different apps.
I just don't know how to realize that...

Thanks in advance

EDIT : [image]
I would like something like that.
X "independant" rings where i can rotate each one separatly.

[image: 3 Button circles]

EDIT 2 : area click
[image]
The button appear as a circle --> OK

But the shape of the area click is still a square.
In my case I need precision, i can't afford to apply listener of button 1 when the user click of button 2.

Not sur if i am understandble... Please say if not.

Comment: An Asthma Test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** - Reworked Code For Shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#808080" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</shape>
```

Set this as background of your button and add Manual Height & width to button. Your button will show up.

**EDIT**
Use Framelayout to overlay your buttons over each other. Change the sizes of button as per your liking. Animated the buttons (rotation) when a button gets clicked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/oval_green"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/oval_blue"
            android:text="Button" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Buttons are under FrameLayout. Now attach code to them and test. both buttons are working fine. I hope this put you in the right path.

**EDIT** - With ImageView
Ensure to cut the Images in proper portions.
[image: Circles]

Your layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivLarge"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/large" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMedium"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/medium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSmall"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/small" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Your MainActivity.java

```
package com.auvitronics.testing;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    public static final String TAG = "TransparentButton";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ImageView ivLarge = findViewById(R.id.ivLarge);
        final ImageView ivMedium = findViewById(R.id.ivMedium);
        ImageView ivSmall = findViewById(R.id.ivSmall);

        ivLarge.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        ivMedium.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        ivSmall.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        ivLarge.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
            {

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());

                if (pixel == Color.TRANSPARENT)
                {
                    System.out.println("Large Transparent Color");
                    return false;
                }else {
                    view.setRotation(view.getRotation() + 90);
                    System.out.println("Large Colored Area");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });

        ivMedium.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
            {

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());

                if (pixel == Color.TRANSPARENT)
                {
                    System.out.println("Medium Transparent Color");
                    return false;
                }else {
                    view.setRotation(view.getRotation() - 90);
                    System.out.println("Medium Colored Area");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });

        ivSmall.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());

                if (pixel == Color.TRANSPARENT)
                {
                    System.out.println("Small Transparent Color");
                    return false;
                }else {
                    view.setRotation(view.getRotation() + 45);
                    System.out.println("Small Colored Area");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And the Result is 
[image]

Comment: Hello Ali Jibran ! First of all, thank you for your answer.
I know how to make a ring. Pls see my EDIT for what I would like. I appreciate.

Comment: Hello Ali Jibran. FrameLayout is OK. But the area click is a square. So when i click on the "big" button at certain place, it applies on the small button (Plz see my Edit for area click).
Maybe should I test the color of the pixel ?
(I still accept this answer ! Thank you !)

Comment: Then you should work with imageView. cut your circle (image of runes) properly with transparency, use their OnTouchListener property and their check the x,y pixel color to process touch event. If i got time, i'll update the answer with the appropriate code hopefully

Comment: OK il will try that !
for the rotation, i've seen this (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer--mobile-8868) wich works fine ! It works with Bitmap so i already change Button to ImageView :-)

Comment: check now. the button is working as you want. You can add animation to your liking

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you Ali Jibran !